# Conditional output based on taxonomy ID of custom post

Tags: terms

I'm working on a conditional statement to either output only the post thumbnail or a post thumbnail and a link for a custom post.

The output is based on a check if the post uses a specific taxonomy ID.

Getting the taxonomy ID of the post isn't an issue, however creating the conditional statement is.

This is the current code:

```
<?php $term = get_the_terms( $post_object->ID, 'my_taxonomy_name' );
// This if statement has to be incorrect
 if($term->term_id == 4 ):?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_object->ID, 'full'); ?></a>
// It always returns the following                          
<?php else:?>

<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_object->ID, 'full'); ?>

<?php endif;?>
```

This is the output of `var_dump($term);`

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#10440 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> 
string(4) "Case" ["slug"]=> string(4) "case" ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(4) ["taxonomy"]=> string(16) "soort_referentie" 
["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(2) 
["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } }
```

Any pointers to help me solve this issue are much appreciated.

Updated code with the solution:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_object->ID, 'my_taxonomy_name' );

foreach($terms as $term){;                                                                                      

    if($term->term_id === 4 ):?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_object->ID, 'full'); ?></a>

    <?php else:

    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_object->ID, 'full');
    break;                          
    endif;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/ gets all terms of the post (which could be several); even if you have only one term, you still need to check the first array element.

Comment: That was the issue indeed, thanks! I've updated the question with the correct code.

Answer (score -1):

Change operator to:

```
 if($term->term_id === 4 ):
```

Check this for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/12785113

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I'm only still getting only the output of the `else` statement for all posts which isn't correct.